# Book Recommendation for Iterated Functions?

Tags: book-recommendation, function-and-relation-composition, fixed-point-iteration, fixed-points

I'm trying to study iterated functions on my own, but I'm having a little trouble. The online resources are scarce, and the textbook that I checked out from a nearby college library references things that I haven't already learned; namely the expansion of a function about a fixed point. I have math knowledge up to the basics of single-variable calculus. Can anybody recommend a good book that can introduce me to the basics of fixed-point iteration before I dive in headfirst?

Comment: Which textbook have you checked out from the library?

Comment: "Early days in Complex Dynamics: A History of Complex Dynamics in One Variable During 1906-1942. The book itself isn't hard to understand, and the little bits of history in between the paragraphs about math keep the book from being too dense. It's just that there are a few things that it assumes the reader already knows.

Comment: A very nice book!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an introduction to fixed-point theorems, try this book:

> [Fixed Points](http://bookstore.ams.org/mawrld-2) by Yu. A. Shashkin

For an introduction to the dynamics of iterated functions, try this book:

> [An Introduction to Chaotic Dynamical Systems](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00C7GBB30) by Robert L. Devaney

Comment: Thank you! I will definitely check that out (or buy it), but it may be some time until I get a chance to do so. Until then, can you recommend any online resources that can be easily accessed?