# Books about fixed-point theory

Tags: banach-spaces, book-recommendation, fixed-point-theorems, fixed-points

I am looking for book recommendations about Fixed-Point Theory. I found this post:

[Book Recommendation for Iterated Functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2256705/book-recommendation-for-iterated-functions)

recommending a book by Shashkin. However, I cannot find who Shashkin is, or his/her affiliation. I also found ["Fixed Point Theory"](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387001739) by Granas and Dugundji; but I have not found reviews of that book.

What books about fixed-point theory can you recommend?

Comment: I am fond of Kantorovich & Akilov's "Functional Analysis". I like their no-nonsense style of exposition.

Comment: @copper.hat thanks for your reply. There has been no answers so far. Would you mind writing your comment as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit old at this point, but I'll add my suggestions in case you're still searching.  These are my top two suggestions.  *Topics* is relatively short and terse, but a very good text to get a foundation in FP theory.  The *Handbook* is still relatively recent and contains an encyclopedic amount of information on the past and (nearly) present state of metric/Banach space FP theory.  I'm happy to offer more suggestions if these don't suit you for whatever reason.

*Topics in Metric Fixed Point Theory* by Goebel and Kirk, URL: **https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/topics-in-metric-fixed-point-theory/57722E4F15554BDFEFABAE390761F00E**

*Handbook of Metric Fixed Point Theory* by many authors, Kirk and Sims editors, URL: 
**https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-94-017-1748-9**

Comment: What are the prerequisites of the first book ($i.e$ Topics...)?

Comment: I would say you should have a solid background in real analysis (convergence properties of sequences, metric spaces, notions of continuity) and basic functional analysis/Banach space geometry.

Comment: I'm reading Kreyszig's functional analysis book. Could I read both at the same time?

Comment: I could imagine a situation where you’re diligently studying Topics and then use Kreyszig as a reference when functional analytic results are needed in Topics. I would suggest you understand the notions of norm convergence/compactness versus weak convergence/compactness and the role that reflexivity plays in these distinctions.